# Want to create Serialized Field that is a list, and has Enumerated options

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This works for creating a field that has a drop down box with all available options.

```
   [System.Serializable]
    private enum researchTypes
    {
        PHYSICS, BIOLOGY, ENGINEERING, ALL, NONE
    }
```

This does not work when I try to do the same thing, except now with the intention of being able to list several enumerated items.

```
    [System.Serializable]
    private enum worldCardTagTypes
    {
        NONE, ROCKY, ICE, MINIMAL_GRAVITY, GAS_GIANT //
    }


    [SerializeField] List<worldCardTagTypes> worldCardTags = new List<worldCardTagTypes>;
```

My goal is to be able to edit a list of tags. If there is something wrong with how I asked this question, please feel free to comment on that, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not rather use a [`Flags`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute) instead

```
[Flags]
private enum researchTypes
{
    // Important that the values are 2^X so they aren't overlapping on a bits level 
    PHYSICS = 1,
    BIOLOGY = 2,
    ENGINEERING = 4
}

[SerializeField] private researchTypes worldCardTags;
```

For this Unity will show a drop-down where you can select multiple items.

Afaik by default it will include also a `Nothing` (==0) and `Everything` (==bitwise "sum"/combination of all) option.

You then use [bitwise and shift operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators) to combine, invert and check for certain values.

E.g. for [combining or appending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39005466/c-sharp-flagged-enums-how-to-append-value) multiple values use bitwise OR

```
var physicsAndBiology = researchTypes.PHYSICS | researchTypes.BIOLOGY;
```

For [checking if a certain flag is contained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339976/how-to-check-if-any-flags-of-a-flag-combination-are-set) either bitwise AND

```
var hasPhysics = physicsAndBiology & researchTypes.PHYSICS == researchTypes.PHYSICS;
```

or also

```
 var hasPhysics = physicsAndBiology.HasFlag(researchTypes.PHYSICS);
```

If you want to check if **any** of some given flags is set you can use e.g.

```
var hasPhysicsOrBiologyOrBoth = worldCardTags & researchTypes.PHYSICS & researchTypes.BIOLOGY != 0;
```

or if you want to check if both flags are set then

```
var hasPhysicsAndBiology = worldCardTags.HasFlag(researchTypes.PHYSICS | researchTypes.BIOLOGY);
```

Comment: This looks like it answers my question. Thank you very much.